# How to create service method interceptor in grails?

Tags: grails, inversion-of-control

I'd like to add some service method interceptor into my grails application. Interceptor should be a Spring managed object (it should be possible to inject whatever I want into it). and I want to specify which service/methods to intercept. As I understand it should be something like spring bean definition in 'conf/spring/resources.groovy', in other words, I'd like to use typical Spring approach. Strange, but I can't find any info on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Spring docs on AOP and this post http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/10/19/grails-plumbing-spring-aop-interceptors/